# How to import json data form web api into SQL Server

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I want to insert data from Web API (strava web api) into SQL Server.

I found function `openjson` but it's for raw data but if use url instead of raw data, which function can i use it.

Example:

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @json = "https://www.strava.com/api/v3/activities?access_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

SELECT * FROM  
 OPENJSON ( @json )  
WITH (   
              Number   varchar(200) '$.Order.Number' ,  
              Date     datetime     '$.Order.Date',  
              Customer varchar(200) '$.AccountNumber',  
              Quantity int          '$.Item.Quantity'  
)
```

Comment: Of course it's possible. What is not possible is answering such a vague question ;)

Comment: First call the web api and store the json on the database, then find out how to properly query it. Although you can, you might want to access web services from outside of the database, it will give you more problems than solutions otherwise.

Comment: SQL Server is not the rigth tool to achieve data from the web. It is possible, there are some tricks, but all of them are rather hacky and old-fashioned. SQL Server is good on data manipulation but needs to get data - and not the address of this data somewhere on the net... Read the JSON with any application you like and pass the JSON to SQL-Server for further actions.

Answer (score 0):

You might be better putting this into an SSIS package, I have done similar in the past following this post: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/545549/UsingplusRESTplusAPIplusinplusSSISplustoplusExtrac